# Google Analytics 4 and AMP - confusion for setup

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I've successfully set up a new Google Analytics 4 property. Under "Web Stream details", it clearly gives me a measurement ID of `G-BR6HXXXXXX`.

The [Google Analytics AMP setup code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/) looks as though it should look like this:

```
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "vars": {
            "gtag_id": "G-BR6HXXXXXX",
            "config": {
              "G-BR6HXXXXXX": { "groups": "default", "site_speed_sample_rate": 100 }
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-analytics>
```

However, this doesn't appear to collect any data, complaining, with an error message in the console:

`log.js:258 [AmpAnalytics <unknown id>] No triggers were found in the config. No analytics data will be sent.`

(Triggers aren't required here; this code should automatically measure page views; and adding triggers doesn't appear to fix this issue.)

I can switch the measurement ID to my old GA one - `UA-1002XXXXX-1` - and it works fine.

I'm now confused as to what's up. Have I found the "wrong" GA AMP-HTML setup page? What should this look like? Why isn't AMP being linked-to from the "web stream" setup for Google Analytics 4?

Comment: Since I think this is a bug - at least, poor documentation - I've also reported this as a bug in amp-html's github repo over here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/30903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Universal Analytics.
GA4 is not yet supported in AMP

You can follow the issue:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24621

Read comment:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24621#issuecomment-824336265

Comment: You're right; and it seems that AMP is another thing of Google's that they don't really care about any more. Thanks.